# How to only fill in empty cells by using VLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets

I have sheet sA and sheet sB.

Sheet sA has column F "claim" and column N "date" (with a lot of missing values).

Sheet aB has column A "claim" and column B "date".

How can i fill in only missing values in sheet sA column N by matching on the claim columns? That is, without overwriting the existing "date" values.

I tried this one, but it's giving me "Circular dependency detected" error:

```
=IF(F2<>"", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2, sB!A:B, 2, FALSE), N2), "")
```

tried this one too, but it also doesn't work

```
=VLOOKUP(F2, sB!A:B, 2 ,FALSE)
```

Comment: It means some of the formula in your cells in `sB!A:B` refers back to cell in which this formula is placed either indirectly or directly.  Thus making a circle.  It is not the formula itself, but the fact that the referenced cells already are linked in another formula causing the search area/criteria to be dependent on the result cell.

Comment: Or, you are putting this formula in F2, which it cannot do.  A formula cannot refer to itself.  You will need to use code if this is the setup.

Comment: @ScottCraner right, i'm first checking if the value exists in the column, and if it doesn't, then I want to fill it in using VLOOKUP. It seems that I have to create a whole new column and reference the other column in it. I can't just look at the column itself and check for empty cells within it.

Comment: correct the formula cannot refer to itself.  you will need code for that.

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: I am thinking a third sheet that evaluates both sets of data might do what you are trying to accomplish.  In third sheet are the list of claims.  The formula would look at this list and then compare to range in sA for the values needed; if a value can't be found, then it would look at range in sB.

Comment: @Codedabbler yeah, i was trying to do it without creating extra sheets/columns :< ... cuz then i have to copy paste the generated data over and it's just a hassle lol

Comment: Do you have a sample spreadsheet.  I think this can be done without any additional data manipulation.